# 413 error bing speech

Tags: java, text-to-speech, bing

I am having trouble with the Bing Speech API on Azure. My text is over 1000 characters long and does not generate audio, is there another way to generate the text?

Here is the error:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 413 for URL: https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.ttssample.TTSService.Synthesize(TTSService.java:84)
>       at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.ttssample.TTSSample.main(TTSSample.java:86)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what 413 means:

HTTP/413 RequestEntityTooLarge - Will be returned if the SSML input is larger than what is supported.

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/api-reference-rest/bingvoiceoutput

I cannot find where it states what the limit is but some experimenting shows that a length of 859 characters works but 877 doesn't. So the limit seems to be somewhere in between.

So I guess you have to send that maximum amount of text at each request.